# Como usar uma URL dinâmica para receber as notificações do PayPal?

Tags: php, pagamento-online

Então, eu sei que é possível definir uma URL de notificação através da área do cliente, e sei também que é preciso ativar o recurso de notificação.

Porém, preciso definir a URL de notificação no momento que eu gero o pedido, como posso fazer isso?

Virei a documentação do PayPal e encontrei algumas poucas citações que falaram sobre tal possibilidade, porém, em nenhum momento eles explicaram com clareza como fazer.

A página com mais detalhes que achei foi essa (no final): https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/

Com isso, fiz o seguinte (é só um pedaço do código):

```
$nvp['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'] = $responseNvp['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'];
$nvp['SUBJECT'] = $responseNvp['SUBJECT'];
$nvp['METHOD'] = 'DoExpressCheckoutPayment';
$nvp['NOTIFYURL'] = 'https://dashboard-clayderson.c9users.io/notify-url.php';
$nvp['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION'] = 'SALE';
```

Não funcionou.

Também tentei no SetExpressCheckout e não funcionou. Podem me dar uma luz?

**Detalhe:** não tem como ser um problema na página que irá receber a notificação, porque logo na primeira linha eu fiz com que ele gravasse em um arquivo .txt todos os acessos a página, e não teve nenhum, além disso, usei o IPN Simulator e consegui capturar os dados perfeitamente.

Comment: o que tem no código da página "notify-url.php" ?

Comment: Um file_put_contents pra criar um "log" de acessos e a chamada pra classe responsável por capturar os dados do IPN. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/39plonf4wii6jza/AAAwVS7Uqjq2XOFYeVzWTS6ma?dl=0

Comment: @DanielOmine, essa página de acesso restrito na url de notificação é porque eu não estou online na IDE da Cloud9, essa URL é só pra previsualização, mas quando fiz os testes, tava liberado o acesso pra todo mundo, inclusive fiz uma notificação manualmente usando o IPN Simulator que o PayPal disponibiliza no SandBox deles e funcionou. Quanto a transação, sim, ela está sendo feita com sucesso. Eu até recebo os e-mails de confirmação de pagamento e tals, eu só não sei como verificar se o PayPal está tentando enviar a notificação, porque não tem log disso no SandBox deles, daí estou na dúvida se é

Comment: algum problema no sistema de notificações da SandBox deles, ou se sou eu fazendo algo errado, já que é minha primeira vez integrando o PayPal.

Comment: Mas aí que está o problema.. a url de notificação tem que estar disponível. Deve estar acessível publicamente, independente de você estar logado/online no cloud.

Comment: Olá Clayderson, tudo bem? Estou passando o mesmo problema. Você conseguiu resolver?